# Send An Activity To Stream.io in C#

Tags: c#, stream

I need to send an activity(for example like activity, share activity, comment activity etc) to stream.io. Can anybody help me in this. Below Is an example of LIKE Activity which i want to send to stream.io

```
 _activityService.StoreUniqueActivity(new Activity
                {
                    Actor = $"JunaUser:{userId}",
                    Verb = InteractionMetadata.INTERACTION_LIKE,
                    Object = $"{feedItem.ContentType}:{feedItem.Id}",
                    Time = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("s", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                });
 if (feedItem.Interactions == null)
                    feedItem.Interactions = new InteractionMetadata
                    {
                        Likes = 0,
                        Shares = 0,
                        Pins = 0
                    };
                feedItem.Interactions.Likes++;
                _feedItemRepository.Upsert(feedItem);
```

Comment: It is not clear what you want to do - stream.io contains classes for reading & writing data to a variety of sources. Do you want to save the activity in a file or send it via the serial port or over the network? Also note that if you need to expand on a question - then you can edit that question - you do not need to post another question.

Comment: @PaulF He's talking about something like https://getstream.io or similar.  There are libraries for that - stream-net for instance.

Comment: i want to send it via serial port @PaulF

Comment: If you are writing the applications to both send & receive the data - then it is up to you to decide on the format used. If the data is being received by a third-party application - then you need to know the required format of the data.